# Reading consecutive messages

Tags: c, server, message, nonblocking

I have created a server and trying to listen on a specific port. When I am sending a message with netcat to this specific port, I succeed reading the first message, with the

`read(fd_client_serv, buf, sizeof(buf));`

system call. After that, any message sent will not be printed. Why is that happening?

Here is my code:

```
void start_server(void)
{

    int fd_serv, fd_client_serv, bytes_read;
    struct sockaddr_in client_serv_addr;
    char buf[2048];

    socklen_t sin_len_serv = sizeof(client_serv_addr);

    fd_serv = initialize_server(get_serving_port());
    fd_set_blocking(fd_serv, 0);

    while(1)
    {
        fd_client_serv = accept(fd_serv, (struct sockaddr *) &client_serv_addr, &sin_len_serv);

        puts("HA!!! you cannot block me!!!");
        sleep(2);
        memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
        write(fd_client_serv, "thank you for answering", 30);
        bytes_read = read(fd_client_serv, buf, sizeof(buf));
        printf("%d\n", bytes_read);
        fflush(stdout);
        printf("%s\n", buf);
    }
}


int initialize_server(int port)
{

    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

    int fd_temp;

    int on = 1;

    fd_temp = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (fd_temp < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    setsockopt(fd_temp, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(int));

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    if (bind(fd_temp,(struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1)
    {
        perror("bind");
        close(fd_temp);
        exit(1);
    }
    if (listen(fd_temp, 10) == -1)
    {
        perror("listen");
        close(fd_temp);
        exit(1);
    }
    return fd_temp;
}


int fd_set_blocking(int fd, int blocking)
{
    /* Save the current flags */
    int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
    if (flags == -1)
        return 0;

    if (blocking)
        flags &= ~O_NONBLOCK;
    else
        flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
    return fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags) != -1;
}
```

I just noticed that if I shutdown netcat (or telnet) and start a new one, I can read again the first message sent. But that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`accept()` accepts a new connection. So every time through the loop you set `fd_client_serv` to the socket id of a new connection, abandoning the old connection. ("Abandoning" in the sense that you will never `read` from it again, since you have lost its id. You haven't closed it but you've forgotten about it.)

Comment: So I have to somehow repeat only my `read code` right? 
Or should I set my `fd_client_serv` outside the `while` loop?

Comment: Exactly. "Somehow" -> put it in a loop.